# Replacing multi-line strings inside xml tags using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have been trying a while to get this working but not having luck. Here is my text file (first.txt)

```
<metric>
 <baseFilter>
  <and>
   <or>
    <value field="id">1111</value>
    <value field="id">2222</value>
   </or>
   <or>
    <value field="resolution" />
   </or>
</metric>
```

I want to replace the strings between the first "or" and "/or" with these strings which is second text file (second.txt). I can have 50 or more value field lines between the first "or" and "/or", hence, i am searching for strings between "or" and "/or" and replacing with whatever in second.txt.

```
<value field="id">3333</value>
<value field="id">4444</value>
```

### Expected output:

```
<metric>
 <baseFilter>
  <and>
   <or>
    <value field="id">3333</value>
    <value field="id">4444</value>
   </or>
   <or>
    <value field="resolution" />
   </or>
</metric>
```

I have got the following perl code for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $first = 'first.txt';
open (my $fh, '<', $first) or die "cannot open file $first";
{
  local $/;
  $first = <$fh>;
}

$find = "([\s]+)(<or>)([\n\r\s]+).*(\n|.)+?([\n\r\s]+)(<\/or>)";

my $content = 'second.txt';
open (my $fh, '<', $content) or die "cannot open file $content";
{
 local $/;
 $content = <$fh>;
}

$first =~ s/$find/$1$2$3$content$5$6/;
print "After sub First is $first\n\n";
```

When I run my code, the substitution is not happening and my $first remains the same, ie, first.txt appears again.  What am I missing ? I used my regex in an online regex tester like http://www.regexr.com/, my regex matches the multi-line string between the first "or" and "/or". 
Why is perl not liking my regex ?

Comment: can't you just search for `#<value field="id">.*?</value>\s+<value field="id">.*?</value>#m` and replace that?

Comment: The reason I am searching for string between the first "or" and "/or" is that I could have 50 value field lines and I need to replace with whatever in second.txt.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to state that, in that case...

Comment: I feel like someone needs to mention http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3897316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things in your match by trying to capture all those pieces of XML. The following regex is a much simpler way to perform the substitution:

```
$first =~ s#(<or>\s+)<value field="id">.*?</value>(\s*</or>)#$1$content$2#sm;
```

I've used the modifiers `s` and `m`, which allow matching over multiple lines, and allow `.` to include new line characters; thus we can replace any number of lines between the `<or>` opening and closing tags. I've also used `#` as a delimiter for my regex so I don't have to faff around with escaping the slashes in the XML close tags.

See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) for more information on regular expressions and in particular, on modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it is a *very bad idea* to manipulate XMNL using regular expressions. So that you can see how simple it is to do things "properly", this program does what you ask using the [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) module.

- An XML parser object is created and used to parse each line of the `second.xml` file, putting them into the `@fragments` array for use later
- The `first.xml` file is parsed, and `findnodes` finds all the `or` elements, the first of which is emptied with `removeChildNodes` and filled again with each line from `@fragments` using `appendChild`
- Finally the XML is formatted using `toString` and printed

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new(no_blanks => 1);

open my $fh, '<', 'second.xml';
my @fragments = map {
   chomp;
   $parser->parse_balanced_chunk($_);
} <$fh>;
close $fh;

my $xml = $parser->load_xml(location => 'first.xml');

my @or_nodes = $xml->findnodes('//or');
$or_nodes[0]->removeChildNodes;
$or_nodes[0]->appendChild($_) for @fragments;

print $xml->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metric>
  <baseFilter>
    <and>
      <or>
        <value field="id">3333</value>
        <value field="id">4444</value>
      </or>
      <or>
        <value field="resolution"/>
      </or>
    </and>
  </baseFilter>
</metric>
```

Answer (score 0):

First load your new values into an array.

Then use `$INPLACE_EDIT` to edit your file using logic like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @newvals = qw(3333 4444);

while (<DATA>) {
    s{<value field="id">\K\w+(?=</value>)}{shift @newvals}e if @newvals;
    print;
}

__DATA__
<metric>
 <baseFilter>
  <and>
   <or>
    <value field="id">1111</value>
    <value field="id">2222</value>
   </or>
   <or>
    <value field="resolution" />
   </or>
</metric>
```

Outputs:

```
<metric>
 <baseFilter>
  <and>
   <or>
    <value field="id">3333</value>
    <value field="id">4444</value>
   </or>
   <or>
    <value field="resolution" />
   </or>
</metric>
```